# Please help me cook :(

Tags: riddle, story

I had the worst day today. My car broke down, I was late to work, I forgot my lunch, and to top it all off, my chef is on holidays. Due to being an emotional eater, it is during times like these when I miss his cooking the most.

To make me feel better, I made up my mind that I was going to cook one of his recipes today.  I sneaked into his quarters to steal his recipe book. To my surprise, when I looked through his drawers, I found no recipe books, however I did find lots of papers containing ingredients which don’t make any sense, however the instructions for cooking were quite clear.

To not leave any evidence behind, I only took one of the papers however I can’t seem to figure out the ingredients. Can you please help me figure them out? Otherwise I will need to sleep hungry tonight.

> **Ingredients**
>
> 1. You loser, you can’t have me for dinner. This right here is only for a winner. -  750g
>
>    A part of me is a street, and a part of me you may sow. - 3 tbsps
>
>    Sweet, but if no money, no me. - 6 tbsps
>
>    If you mix me with water when cooking, you might get hurt. - 1/4 cup
>
>    A part of me can happen on your foot with pressure and the other part is a powder. May also be an ingredient when cooking bread. - 4 tbsps
>
>    A plain version of the above (#5) used in cooking bread. - 1/4 cup
>
>    This powder helps in raising. - 1 cup
>
>    COO HIJKLMNO. - 1/2 cup
>
>    Found in waters of our ocean and on the table of our home. - 1/2 tsp
>
> **Method**
>
> Combine 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9. Mix them with a whisk and leave it to rest. After 20 mins, chop and dice 1, and also mix it in nicely with the above mixture.
>
> Get a pan and get it hot, add 4 and wait.
>   Once you see the pan bubbling, add 1s out of your mixture and take out once ready.
>
> Mix the 1s with the 3s and sprinkle on the 2s.

*If you can help me figure out the ingredients, my chef’s recipe is yours (I don’t think he will mind). Have fun cooking everybody.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ingredients are

> 1. Chicken ("winner winner chicken dinner")
>  2. Sesame seeds (*Sesame Street*, and you can sow seeds)
>  3. Honey (is sweet, and "no money no honey" is a slang phrase for women rejecting men due to financial shortcomings)
>  4. Oil (from simonalexander2005, mixing oil with boiling water causes it to spit)
>  5. Corn flour (you can have corns on your feet, and flour is a powder; it's also used to make cornbread)
>  6. All-purpose flour (a generic version of flour)
>  7. Baking powder (a leavening agent)
>  8. $ CO_2 + H_2O $ (letters span from "H to O") = Carbonated water
>  9. Salt (sea salt and table salt)

Based on these ingredients and the method, we are making

> honey-glazed chicken, specifically [this recipe](https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/recipes/honey-chicken-recipe-3/smlmzznw) found by Silent Axe.

Combine 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9. Mix them with a whisk and leave it to rest.

> This makes the batter that will coat the chicken.

After 20 mins, chop and dice 1, and also mix it in nicely with the above mixture

> This coats the chicken to be fried.

Get a pan and get it hot, add 4 and wait. Once you see the pan bubbling, add 1s out of your mixture and take out once ready.

> This fries the chicken and hopefully makes it super crispy.

Mix the 1s with the 3s and sprinkle on the 2s.

> This completes the dish by adding a bit of sweetness (from the honey) and nuttiness (from the sesame seeds) to it. The final product is also perfect for your situation, since fried chicken of any variety is a common comfort food.

Comment: Could #7 be: (rot13) "envfvat pnar" (Pnva) - yvxr pnar fhtne

Comment: #4 if it's hot and you add water to it, it'll spit

Comment: 7 is probably: (rot13) "onxvat cbjqre", a leavening agent.

Comment: Using your answer I found exact recipe [here](https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/recipes/honey-chicken-recipe-3/smlmzznw).
Although #7 in OP probably has a typo

Answer (score 1):

1.

> Chicken (Winner winner chicken dinner)

2. --

3.

> Honey (No money no honey sunny bunny (Vice City))

4. --
5. --
6. --
7. --
8. --

9.

> Salt

vinegar

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:

1. You loser, you can’t have me for dinner. This right here is only for a winner. -  750g

> Chicken. Winner winner, chicken dinner

2. A part of me is a street, and a part of me you may sow. - 3 tbsps
3. Sweet, but if no money, no me. - 6 tbsps

> Sugar? Sugar daddy/mummy?

4. If you mix me with water when cooking, you might get hurt.  - 1/4 cup

> Oil. Adding oil to boiling water can be disastrous

5. A part of me can happen on your foot with pressure and the other part is a powder. May also be an ingredient when cooking bread. - 4 tbsps

> Mushrooms? Not sure, going off fungus on feet.

6. A plain version of the above (#5) used in cooking bread. 1/4 cup

> Not sure, but guessing this is yeast

7. This powder helps in raising. 1 cup

> Self-raising flour

8. COO HIJKLMNO. - 1/2 cup

> Sparkling water. Co2, H to O (H20).

9. Found in waters of our ocean and on the table of our home.  1/2 tsp

> Salt